# How to run firefox program in linux and get its output on windows

Tags: linux, centos7, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have one centos 7 (minimum setup) installed on cloud .
I m connect it using using `putty` on my laptop.

I have installed Firefox on centos server which has fast internet connection.

However whenever i run Firefox its not loading because it doesn't have GUI installed (and i m connecting it using `putty`).

I want to browse internet on it from windows machine. How can i go about it?

Error Message

```
# firefox
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply Firefox with a virtual graphic screen. You could for example install [XMing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) on Windows, and configure PuTTY to "forward X connection".

Then Firefox will "draw" on the screen, and the screen will be transmitted to your PC. Your mouse and keyboard signals will be transmitted to the remote server.

This setup should go about six times as slow than your current Web connection, since your connection to the Internet, which is the bottleneck, is unchanged, and now you're pushing massive X data on it instead of browsing elements.

A better possibility would be to install *Squid* proxy on the remote server, then configure your PuTTY to open a "tunnel" from remote port 127.0.0.1:3128 to local port 3128, and finally instructing your Windows Firefox to use 127.0.0.1 on port 3128 as proxy for all protocols.

This way, the browsing information will be downloaded remotely, compressed and forwarded to you.

This should be around twice as slow as your current connection (unless you're connecting with old Web sites without gz/deflate support, and mostly text with no images. In that case you might experience a connection up to five times as fast, albeit with a somewhat increased latency.

(An even better but even more complicated setup involves running a local proxy, connected through SSH tunnel to a remote proxy).

In all cases your navigation might appear as coming from the remote machine, but to ensure there's no information leak, you need to properly configure the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to connect

```
$ ssh -Y whatever.com
```

On the Centos server, edit the file /etc/X11/sshd_config, it will be necessary to turn on X11 forwarding with a line like

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

In the putty Enable X11 forwarding in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward X over SSH, but it is painfully slow. Something like NoMachine will do far better.

However, if you are trying to get faster internet, you may be out of luck as any attempt to improve this will just add overhead.

You may be able to set up a VPN to improve the compression on data you receive from other websites. Take a look at [this SO post](https://superuser.com/questions/254366/internet-compression-proxy-for-low-speed-broadband) for some information about what's available and what solutions already exist.